# HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; (Error)

Tags: java, android

So I am following along in the Sunshine App for Developing Android Apps course on Udacity. For some reason, this is showing up as an error and I haven't found a solution anywhere.

Why is this statement unreachable?

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
```

The `MainActivity` Code:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 66/73",
                "Tomorrow - Sunny - 65/71",
                "Sunday - Rainy - 59/66",
                "Monday - Cloudy - 59/65",
                "Tuesday - Cloudy - 60/66",
                "Wednesday - Sunny - 61/68",
                "Thursday - Sunny - 62/70"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                // The current context (this fragment's parent)
                getActivity(),
                // ID of list item layout
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                // ID of the textView to populate
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                // Forecast data
                weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
                R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Uniontown&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=");

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For postin online you sould generally always remove the appid - please edit your post. Secondly where does the error happen? Can you post the logcat output? Also, just in general, you can checkout the next version from Udacity's github or go on to the solution video in case you are facing difficulties in the future, just sayin

Comment: What do you mean the appid? The package name? Not sure how to get the logcat either if it won't execute

Comment: In the url string you have your appid posted. Remove it...

Comment: Oh yeah.. forgot I added that, thanks

Comment: can you post the exact error statement ? its a compile time error right?

Comment: yeah it is a compile time error. It simply says that it's an unreachable statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the onCreateView() method stops executing when it reaches this statement

```
return rootview;
```

put that as the last line of your function

Comment: HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; (Unreachable statement)

Comment: for more details on why return  stops the execution check out this http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=280

comment if the solution does not work or you have any more doubts

Comment: when i move the return rootview; anywhere else it cannot resolve the symbol 'rootview' where it's at now is where it has no errors

Comment: on further inspection i found that you have another return rootview statement at the right place. just remove the one before 

 // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

Comment: that did it! I forgot I had two as well lol, thanks for the help and extra set of eyes.